# a support to simplify a still written code about circular heatmap

Tags: heatmap, circular-dependency

I saw a post about circular heatmap:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/242473/

in the graph linked (https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4ujP.png) how do I simplify the code to have only a visualization of data1:

```
data1={{9., 1., 6., 7., 6., 3., 1., 3., 10., 2., 2., 5., 2., 5., 3.,
1.}, {5., 5., 5., 4., 4., 6., 4., 6., 9., 1., 2., 10., 2., 1., 1.,
6.}, {2., 7., 6., 2., 8., 10., 8., 9., 2., 5., 3., 9., 7., 8., 7.,
5.}, {6., 6., 2., 1., 8., 2., 8., 3., 8., 5., 5., 4., 6., 2., 3.,
6.}, {8., 1., 8., 2., 5., 8., 5., 3., 5., 3., 4., 2., 2., 4., 4.,
1.}, {2., 2., 1., 1., 0., 2., 2., 3., 2., 0., 2., 0., 2., 0., 0.,
9.},{10., 2., 2., 5., 10., 10., 15., 15., 2., 2., 10., 10., 15., 15., 10.,
2.}};
SeedRandom[1]
data2 = RandomReal[{25, 100}, {8, Last@Dimensions@data1}];
data3 = RandomInteger[{10, 30}, {4, Last@Dimensions@data1}];



{rowlabels1, rowlabels2, rowlabels3} = Style[2010 + #, 16] & /@
Range[First@Dimensions@#] & /@ {data1, data2, data3};

radialorigin = 4;
radialorigin2 = radialorigin + 1 + First @ Dimensions @ data1;
radialorigin3 = radialorigin2 + 1 + First @ Dimensions @ data2;

radialorigins = {radialorigin,radialorigin2,radialorigin3};

colors = {"Rainbow", "Rainbow", "SolarColors"};

charts = MapThread[
SectorChart[preProcessData[#, 1/4, #2],
SectorOrigin -> {{Pi/2, "Counterclockwise"}, #3},
ChartBaseStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[{Opacity[1], White}]],
LabelingFunction -> #4,
ChartElementFunction -> Append[ConstantArray["Sector", Length@First@#], {} &],
ImageSize -> 1 -> 15, SectorSpacing -> {0, 0}] &,
{{data1, data2, data3}, colors, radialorigins,
{None, None, labelingFunction[First @ Dimensions @ data3, columnlabels]}}];

legends = MapThread[Inset[circularLegend[Min @ #, Max @ #,  #2],
{radialorigin + First[Dimensions @ data1]/2, #3 +
First[Dimensions @ #]/2}, Center, Scaled[{.12, .12}]] &,
{{data1, data2, data3}, colors, radialorigins}];

ClearAll[histogramLegend]
histogramLegend = SmoothHistogram[Flatten@#, MaxExtraBandwidths -> 0,
PlotRange -> {MinMax @ #, Automatic}, PlotLabel -> #3,
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData[#2][x]],
Filling -> Axis, Axes -> {True, False}, AspectRatio -> 1/8,
PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.02],
PlotStyle -> LineOpacity -> 0] &;

histolegends = MapThread[histogramLegend,
{{data1, data2, data3}, colors,
Style["ss " <> ToString @ #, 10] & /@ Range[3]}];

legends3 = MapThread[Inset[#2, {radialorigin + First[Dimensions@data1]/3, #3 +
First[Dimensions@#]/2}, Left, Scaled[{.3, .2}]] &,
{{data1, data2, data3}, histolegends, radialorigins}];

Show[charts,
Epilog -> {legends3,
MapThread[MapIndexed[Function[{x, y},
Text[x, Offset[{30, 0}, {0, # - 1/2 + y[[1]]}]]], #2] &,
{radialorigins, {rowlabels1, rowlabels2, rowlabels3}}],
MapThread[Text[#2, Offset[{0, 20}, {#, 0}]] &,
{radialorigins + (Dimensions[#][[1]]/2 & /@ {data1, data2, data3}),
Style[" " <> ToString@#, 16] & /@ Range[3]}]},
PlotRange -> All]
```

I'd like to see the circular heatmap and the area graph on the right only for data1